# Can we get a more awesome captcha image for Area 51?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, captcha

On Area 51 I finally hit a captcha and was instantly depressed. It's the same as the Stack Overflow captcha :(

Can we please get something more specific and awesome for Area 51, hopefully falling in line with the rest of the theme.

Comment: Dumb question:   What's a capcha?   Is it the human-checker?

Comment: @jay Yes. It is.

Comment: Finally? I get those things about every five minutes.

Comment: Maybe someone can find a public domain / cc image of the business end of a giant squid. By business end, I mean the razor sharp beak opened wide and waiting to eat you :)

Comment: Wow I add a bounty and instantly get 2 answers in about 5 minutes.

Comment: @Earlz That would be the goal of bounties :)

Comment: Would someone post what it is?

Comment: @C. Ross: CAPTCHA Fail! Look a [little farther](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52603/can-we-get-a-more-awesome-captcha-image-for-area-51/53982#53982) down the page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's alien (well sort of) robots you want:

[image]

(assuming that this was the image I linked to in the first place)

Comment: excellent, we went with this for the captcha!

Comment: @Jeff - that's made my day ;)

Comment: What image was this? Is it the one from [The Invisible Boy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050546/mediaindex) that's currently [used for the captcha](https://area51.stackexchange.com/captcha)?

Comment: @Laurel - I can only assume it was the image of Robbie the Robot that is currently being used. I can't remember for sure and of course the link is dead now.

Answer (score 7):

[image: HAL9000]

source: http://theinvisibleagent.wordpress.com/2009/01/02/famous-robots-from-popular-culture/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's still in copyright. Displaying it as something for the CAPTCHA page (rather than discussing the movie) is out of the grasp of fair use. IANAL, but I have one sitting next to me.

Comment: @Tim isn't that the problem with all suggestions so far? Maybe Terry Colon (Who did the Area 51 artwork) could be asked to draw something based on the top answer.

Comment: That would be ideal.

Answer (score 5):

["Klaatu barada nikto!"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043456/)

[image: Gort]

Comment: Gort! Klaatu barada nikto!

Comment: Aww, now my comment is obsolete.

Comment: @Randolpho: You can take solace in the fact that your comment inspired me to change the image caption. ;)

Answer (score 5):

[image: WALL-E]
source: http://theinvisibleagent.wordpress.com/2009/01/02/famous-robots-from-popular-culture/

Comment: But Wall-e is an eventual, not parallel future .. I'm quite looking forward to my floating couch.

Comment: Additionally, using this on a captcha page doesn't exactly constitute fair use (we're not discussing the movie on that page, after all).

Answer (score 4):

There's always [good old Cthulhu](https://web.archive.org/web/20140211230152/http://www.codinghorror.com:80/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html):

[image: Cthulhu]
<sub>(source: [typepad.com](https://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86e32a6970b-pi))</sub>

Not sure about ownership issues, though.

**EDIT**

To make a kinder, gentler lord of the abyss and underworld, someone can just write (freehand):

> I CAN HAZ CAPTCHA?

... on the image.

Comment: He's more of a "human-devourer" than a "human-checker". He'd be more likely to leave bots alone than he would humans, so he's kinda the "anti-captcha".

Comment: @gnovices-exchange - good point, see my edit

Comment: And who says Cthulhu is not perfectly preserved somewhere underground in Nevada?

Comment: As to ownership...H.P. Lovecraft is now resting for a good 70 years...if someone is still holding copyright on that, then we have a problem with our system. But, if you mean the picture...there's a signature in the lower left corner...but I'm unable to read it. :/

Comment: @Bobby - yes, I was thinking of the artist when mentioning ownership.

Comment: @Tim Post: I've spent an hour looking for it, but I could only find images about that size (actually, about the same size) or smaller...it's all over the place but noone seems to mention where it came from, sorry. :/

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I think we should go with a Gaius Baltar administering the Cylon Detector Test theme.

Here he is administering the test, with benefits:

[possibly NSFW link](http://peopleareidiots.ca/images/2008/galleries/bsg_screenshots/s01e09-baltar-and-six.jpg)

But that.... might not be fully work safe. So.... here's a pic of him looking at his own brain scan; it's "test-ish" so maybe that'll work.

[image]
<sub>(source: [battlestarwiki.org](http://media.battlestarwiki.org/images/5/54/Brainscan.jpg))</sub>

We could go with just a Cylon:

[image]

Or Old Skool:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There have been any number of human-checking techniques in science fiction. It's an important plot element when the aliens or robots look like humans. Recent (relative to copyright) examples include V and Terminator. I can't think of an example right now that might have an image that's in the public domain.

Comment: I remember V rather fondly :)

Comment: @Tim: The original or the recent one?

Comment: @Dennis - The original one

Comment: If you want to go with V, there's this image, which was iconic back in the 80s...: http://www.blogcdn.com/www.scifisquad.com/media/2009/10/v_original.jpg

Comment: @Randolpho: Definitely not human! Rejected by captcha!

Comment: TV tropes is probably your best bet ... if you're ok with not doing any more work today.

Answer (score 0):

[image: C3PO and R2D2]
source: http://theinvisibleagent.wordpress.com/2009/01/02/famous-robots-from-popular-culture/

Comment: Still, again, much in copyright.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this movie-poster from Houdini's silent movie from 1918 called [The Master Mystery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Master_Mystery) which illustrates the human/robot relation quite well. Though I'm not 100% sure, I believe the robot could be an actual person in a suit..

So considering that possibility we should introduce a captcha to let robots proof that they aren't actually just disguised humans ;)

[image]