# Human verification on Area 51 Discussion Zone is not displayed

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, captcha

See the [robot-captcha image](http://sstatic.net/area51discuss/img/captcha-robot.jpg) or simulate a situation that triggers a human verification.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed, thanks for the report.  See https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/captcha

Comment: I'm disappointed that it's changed from my suggestion - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52603/can-we-get-a-more-awesome-captcha-image-for-area-51/53982#53982 ;)

Comment: @ChrisF sorry about that!  The Q&A sites are less flexible with their layout than Area 51, so I had to find another image that fit at that size

Comment: On the bright side though it's still Robby :)

Comment: @ChrisF yes, and if you find another one you prefer that fits at that size I can change it again :)

Comment: What dimensions does it have to be?

Comment: @ChrisF width is fixed at 600px, height should be 450px-ish or less